# how can i handle rad window popup by watir script?

Tags: watir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

How can i handle this type of Rad window pop up by using watir.

```
<span id="RadWindowTitlectl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rwmWinManager_rwMessage" class="RadWTitleText" onselectstart="return false;" unselectable="on">Check Results</span>
```

This is for button html...

```
<input id="btnOk" class="LoginButton" type="button" onclick="javascript:CallBackToEdit('1');" value="Ok">
```

Please give guidance for this.

Comment: providing more of the HTML, or at least a sort of outline of where this thing is within the DOM would be really helpful in addressing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Need more info to help you.

If you're trying to access a newly generated popup window, do it something like this:

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the HTML you have supplied just seems to be an ordinary div element, my first guess is that this is not truly any kind of popup, but just a div that is using Ajax/javascript and CSS to simulate the effect of a popup (by manipulating the coloring of objects, and perhaps the 'enabled' state as well so it appears to be modal)

To be sure we'd need to see more than just fragments of the HTML  Or better yet a reference to an example of a page that implements this control.  It would also be helpful to know WHICH set of 'Rad' controls (since Telerik has multiple versions (Ajax, MS-MVC, Silverlight, WPF and Winforms) available) and knowing which one might make it easier to find an example of the control on [the demo pages at Telerik's site](http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx)

based on what little you've provided I would think that simply

```
browser.button(:id, 'btnOK').click  #ought to work
```

Note that since this thing could well be coming into existence via client side scripting, potentially a brief [wait](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/How+to+wait+with+Watir) might be necessary to ensure that the object exists, before trying to click it.

If that does not work for you, then use developer tools to look at the button input element and make sure it is not in a frame.

Otherwise please give us either more HTML, specifics on which RAD control this is (so we can perhaps find an example among their demos) or both.